# Delete everything to the right starting from a specific character

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say my database has a couple of entries

```
2345
2532-1
2593-R2
2380
2013-E1
```

How do I trim everything to the right of the dash '-' including the dash itself while maintaining all the numbers prior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substr` with `instr`, but you need to vary the second argument to `substr` depending on whether the value has a dash at all, which you can do with a case statement:

```
select substr(value, 1,
  case
    when instr(value, '-') > 0 then instr(value, '-') - 1
    else length(value)
  end)
from <your table>;
```

`instr(value, '-')` gives your the position of the first `-` in the value, or zero if it doesn't appear at all. If it is zero then you need the full string, so you can use the length; otherwise you want up to the character before the `-`. Or you can only do the substring at all if there is a `-` and use the raw value otherwise, which is maybe a bit neater:

```
select case
    when instr(value, '-') > 0 then substr(value, 1, instr(value, '-') - 1)
    else value
  end
from <your table>;
```

Quick demo with your sample values:

```
with t (value) as (
  select '2345' from dual
  union all select '2532-1' from dual
  union all select '2593-R2' from dual
  union all select '2380' from dual
  union all select '2013-E1' from dual
)
select value,
  case
    when instr(value, '-') > 0 then substr(value, 1, instr(value, '-') - 1)
    else value
  end
from t;

VALUE   CASEWHE
------- -------
2345    2345   
2532-1  2532   
2593-R2 2593   
2380    2380   
2013-E1 2013
```

You could even use a regular expression which matches everything up to the first `-`:

```
select regexp_substr(value, '[^-]*')
from <your table>
```

... but that might be slower, though the code is shorter.

Comment: Would using NVL work or does it have any repercussions? I actually tried doing NVL(SUBSTR(value, 1, (INSTR(value,'-')) - 1), value) and it worked. Thanks for the "-1" idea.

Comment: @MikeSanchez - I don't think it has any repercussions, though someone coming along later to look at the code might find it harder to understand. (Worse case is your column is not-null, and someone assumes misunderstands, things the NVL is therefore redundant, and removes it - breaking the functionality). Pros and cons to everything though *8-)

Answer (score 0):

First you find the position of the dash via INSTR. 
Then use SUBSTR to get from position 1 to the dash.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value,'-')) FROM table;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to return entries that do not have dashes in them.